# How to create something close to a chat bubble using Qt StyleSheets

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I went through the stylesheet docs, but I am still not sure what/where I should be looking for.

I have a QListBox that I want to style is such a way that each entry in the listbox appears in a chat bubble. The bubble should look something like this or fairly close to it:

[image: Tailed message bubble]

Comment: Do you mean `QListWidget` or are you actually using `QListBox` from Qt 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed using `QListView`/`QListWidget` you can try something like this:

```
setStyleSheet("QListView::item{border-width:25px 25px 50px 25px; border-image: url(:/img/bubble.png) 25 25 50 25 stretch;}");
```

[Read this](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) to learn more about how `border-image` works.

Another option is to subclass [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and draw your bubble in its [`paint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method.